# How can I call method of a class after binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have classes in javascript

```
class TestA {

  findUser() {
    console.log('findUser TEST class')
  }

  start() {
    this.findUser();
  }
}

class TestB extends TestA  {


}

let testB = new TestB();

const A = testB.start.bind(TestB)

A();
```

I cannot call A, I got the error

### TypeError: this.findUser is not a function

I need this because I pass bound method A to props of the react component.

```
<MyComponent start={A} />
```

And I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the method to the **instance, not to the class** itself.

So this should work:

```
const A = testB.start.bind(testB)
```

```js
class TestA {
  findUser() {
    console.log('findUser TEST class')
  }

  start() {
    this.findUser();
  }
}

class TestB extends TestA {}

let testB = new TestB();

const A = testB.start.bind(testB)

A();
```

---

**Update**

After getting an upvote, I noticed that I could've added another option: using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the
> enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
> variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not
> present in the current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the
> `this` from its enclosing scope.

```js
class TestA {
  findUser = () => {
    console.log('findUser TEST class')
  }

  start = () => {
    this.findUser();
  }
}

class TestB extends TestA {}

let testB = new TestB();

const A = testB.start;

A();
```